# how to take mail id of user using the google assistant chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am new to build chat-bots. Here I have made a chat-bot using dialog flow and integrated with google assistant. Is their any way that we can get the mail id of the user interacting with the chat-bot so that we can send mail to their respective id.

Answer (score 0):

Only with the user's permission to give it to you. You can request that they sign in using [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in). When they do so, their profile information is available. If their email address is part of their profile, it will be included.